# Converting redis INFO command response string to JSON object in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

The redis INFO commad returns the string like `redis_version:2.2.14\r\nredis_git_sha1:00000000\r\nredis_git_dirty:0\r\narch_bits:32`

How can I convert the string to get a JSON object something like

```
 { 
     "redis_version":"x",
     "key2":"value"
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why would you want to do that, but here's a simple example:

```
function parseInfo( info ) {
    var lines = info.split( "\r\n" );
    var obj = { };
    for ( var i = 0, l = info.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        var line = lines[ i ];
        if ( line && line.split ) {
            line = line.split( ":" );
            if ( line.length > 1 ) {
                var key = line.shift( );
                obj[ key ] = line.join( ":" );
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but is there any simple solution instead of the workaround like above?

Comment: It is a simple solution and it is not a workaround. What did you expect? That a string will magically parse itself?

Comment: I think even redis authors do encourage people to parse it on their own, since it's a relatively simple string to parse.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [node-redis-info](https://github.com/FGRibreau/node-redis-info):

```
npm install redis-info
```

Usage:

```
> var parser = require('redis-info');
undefined
> var info = parser.parse(redis_info_str);
undefined
> info.fields.redis_version
2.6.1
> info.startWith('pubsub')
[ [ 'pubsub_channels', '2' ],
  [ 'pubsub_patterns', '0' ] ]
> info.contains('memory')
[ [ 'used_memory', '15080416' ],
  [ 'used_memory_human', '14.38M' ],
  [ 'used_memory_rss', '21258240' ],
  [ 'used_memory_peak', '18985904' ],
  [ 'used_memory_peak_human', '18.11M' ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import redis
import json
print(json.dumps(redis.Redis().info()))
```

For **zabbix** Template DB Redis:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import redis
import json
import sys
r = redis.Redis.from_url(sys.argv[1])
a = {}
sections = ["CPU","Clients","Cluster","Keyspace","Memory","Modules","Persistence","Replication","Server","Stats"]
for section in sections:
    a[section]=r.info(section)
print(json.dumps(a))
```

Comment: It's asked to use NodeJS, not python.

Comment: I'm sorry, but let it stay here, it might be useful to someone else

Answer (score 0):

```
interface RedisInfo {
  [key: string]: any;
}

/**
 * This was taken from how `.serverInfo` was parsed in the ioredis library
 * https://github.com/luin/ioredis/blob/f275bc24de3825f80415a69ff227a45251dd1a3b/lib/redis/index.ts#L500
 * @param infoString Result of Redis INFO command
 */
const parseRedisInfo = (infoString: string): RedisInfo => {
  const info: RedisInfo = {};

  const lines = infoString.split('\r\n');
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
    const parts = lines[i].split(':');
    if (parts[1]) {
      info[parts[0]] = parts[1];
    }
  }
  return info;
};
```

[Source](https://github.com/luin/ioredis/blob/f275bc24de3825f80415a69ff227a45251dd1a3b/lib/redis/index.ts#L500)